# Literal type as key of another type

Tags: typescript

```js
type Key = 'foo'  //'Key' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

const Key = 'foo' // OK

type Test={[Key]:string}
```

In the code. I only use type `Key` as another type's property name. Why the `Key` must be a value?

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQOQDMD2GUCgekigBUIBnYRAbwG04QBdALnICcBLAOwHMBfIA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably should use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) of the form `{[P in KeyType]: ValueType}` instead of a *computed property declaration*:

```
type Test = { [K in Key]: string };
/* type Test = {
    foo: string;
} */
```

In cases like this where the value type does not depend on the property, you can also use the built-in [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
type AlsoTest = Record<Key, string>;
/* type AlsoTest = {
    foo: string;
} */
```

---

I can't find a good canonical piece of documentation for this, but in TypeScript, a computed property declaration is of the form `{[value]: Type}`, where `value` is the name of a *value* of a constant [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) or a [`unique symbol` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol).  As a value, `value` must exist at runtime:

```
const key: Key = 'foo';
type ComputedKeyTest = { [key]: string };
/* type ComputedKeyTest = {
    foo: string;
} */

const mySymbol = Symbol("mySymbol");
type ComputedSymbolKey = { [mySymbol]: string };
/* type ComputedSymbolKey = {
    [mySymbol]: string;
} */
```

Because `Key` is a type, but not a value, you get an error if you write `{[Key]: string}`.  Note that you can get the particular type you want here by using `key` instead of `Key`.  But this only works since `Key` is a single string literal and not, for example, a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such literals.  And even so, you shouldn't need to emit a `key` value to JavaScript just to do type manipulations... so the mapped type above is the recommended approach.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=5&pln=17&pc=17#code/FAFwngDgpgBA0lMMC8MDkAzA9ltxSSwAqUAziCjAN4wDacMAlgHbyIC6AXDOQE4sBzGAF8A3MAD0AKhjhoMEuUpVgMNTGxZufQeOEwpE-HNgBBADaksiiqgBKUAMZZeAEwA8CMABoeIfswCAHzi0rKEMBZWNsqq6pra-rrA+ob4zsxKANaI3F6UmDho4iYwAMJYALYQAK4gUK5eMag0tDlgXH4BQmKSMqUV1XUNTWS21HFqCV3JqUYZSpVgAMpglQBGWOaUqxtbABQAREu7m+aHAJQlEYO19a6nW-ktdCdrZ506gSKh-TdVdwaj3Mzwm6leK3eW0+SUCegMRnwQA)